# give 'id' attribute to header

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am creating column as below

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Abc').renderWith(abcRenderer)
```

How can I give `id` to the column header `th`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `column().header()` node by using a unique `:contain` selector in `initComplete` :

```js
.withOption('initComplete', function() {
  var api = this.api();
  api.column(':contains("Abc")').header().id = 'Abc-header-id';
})
```

Note: `.withOption` is associated with `dtOptions` (or whatever you call it)